# Negative match for earlier part of a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that matches filenames, such as:

```
image.png
image.svg
image.gif
```

However, I don't want it to match if my extension is preceded by `.inline`, like so:

```
image.inline.png
image.inline.svg
image.inline.gif
```

My current regular expression matches the first three, and is like so: `/\.(gif|png|svg)$/` - however, I'm having trouble adding in the negative condition for a preceding `.inline`.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also use a negative lookahead, but I would phrase it slightly differently:

```js
var term = "image.inline.png";
var re = new RegExp("^(?!.*\\.inline\\.[^.]+$).*\\.(?:gif|png|svg)$");
if (re.test(term)) {
    console.log("Valid");
} else {
    console.log("Invalid");
}
```

Comment: @think123 The current `new RegExp("^(?!.*\.inline\.[^.]+$).*\.(?:gif|png|svg)")` solution has some issues. You need to use a *regex literal*, `var re = /^(?!.*\.inline\.[^.]+$).*\.(?:gif|png|svg)$/;` (no quotes, no `new RegExp`). Yeah, and add the `$` at the end to ensure you only match extensions at the end of the string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Perhaps, however I'm using the above in Webpack with no issues :) thanks for the info though!

Comment: @think123 You just do not realize that `.` matches any char, that is why you have "no issues". The current solution matches files with, say, `mpng` extension. Since you need to match a dot, you need to escape it. If you plan to use a constructor notation, double backslashes, `var re = new RegExp("^(?!.*\\.inline\\.[^.]+$).*\\.(?:gif|png|svg)$");`. Still, it is uglier than a regex literal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookahead to check for the preceeding `.inline`. See it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/bjqpFx/1/).

```
^\w+(?!\.inline)\.(gif|png|svg)$
```

Comment: I got that from looking at other questions on Stack Overflow; however, the problem is that I don't want to specify which characters can be typed in before the `.inline.svg` part; in other words, I don't want to care about anything, other than if the string ends in `.inline.svg`, whereas your above regex makes assumptions as to the content prior to this segment.

Comment: Normally I would recommend a negative lookbehind in this case, but unfortunately JavaScript's regex engine does not support them. Tim's answer may work better for you.

Comment: This is a totally wrong solution. `(?!\.inline)` restricts `\.(gif|png|svg)` pattern, and is thus always TRUE and plain redundant. Hence, it isn't answering the current question. Please consider fixing or removing since the lookahead is misused here and may bewilder others.